# Display error on Word 2016 when inserting images in header

Tags: vb.net, word-2016

I have a script which fills a word document with additional information. One of them is a logo of the current company. I add this image to the document like this:

```
imgPath = saveFileAsTempFile(oDoc,oFile,"Logotype")
If oFile.FileExists(imgPath) Then
    oExternDoc.Sections(1).headers(2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgPath)
    Set tables = oExternDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range.Tables
    If tables Is  Nothing Then
    Else
        Factor = (tables(1).Rows(1).Height - oExtApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.05)) / oExternDoc.Sections(1).headers(2).Range.InlineShapes(1).Height  * 100
    End If 
    oExternDoc.Sections(1).headers(2).Range.InlineShapes(1).ScaleHeight = Factor
    oExternDoc.Sections(1).headers(2).Range.InlineShapes(1).ScaleWidth = Factor
End If
```

My problem:

There is already a logo in the header which should be overwritten. In Word 2010 the newly inserted logo was added on top of the old logo, so that only the above one was visible, which was totally fine. But now with Word 2016 both logos are displayed one below the other.
Is there a way to put the inserted image on top of the existing one as before?

Word 2010:
[image]

Word 2016:
[image]

Comment: Why not just delete the old logo when there's an image available to cover it? You could simply iterate the InlineShapes collection and remove/replace the old logo with your new one

Comment: I didn't wanna do it because I'm not guite sure, if there are any other images inside the header. But yes, this seems to be the best solution so far.